# Securing an API key

Tags: api

I have a website that stores data for users. I am developing a Wordpress plugin that will allow other websites to access the data stored for each user and upload new data.

For example Joe creates an account on my website and uploads information. Joe installs the plugin on his own website which will give him access to the data he stored on my website from his own website.

Visitors to Joe website will be able to upload data to Joe's account on my website. Joe's website will determine who can access, who can modify and who can upload new information to Joe's account in my website.

I thought about publishing an API on my website and having the Wordpress plugin access it. I understand that Joe's website would have an api key that would allow his website to authenticate to my website. However what would prevent someone else from using that API key and pretending to be Joe's website?

I have seen similar implementations of what I want to do and I can see the api key when I inspect the code on the client side. What would prevent me from using that api key and pretending to be the website?

Is there a way to secure the API key so a visitor to Joe's website does not see it?

I saw this answer here: [How to securely use api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702964/how-to-securely-use-api-key)

However wouldn't the visitor still be able to see the key when Joe's website post it on the request to my website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API Key will be used at server side of the other website to communicate with your website,
so the client won't be able to see it.

The API Key cann't be used directly from the user browser to access your site resources since then it will be [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) which is blocked by the browsers due to security risks.

If the request to your site is also encrypted (https) then even if someone that somehow watching the traffic he won't be able to fetch the API Key.

**How to implement It:**

You should have a URL that can handle other sites requests to update a user profile, for example:

```
www.yoursite.com/api/updateprofile
```

Now you should decide whether you want to support data given by GET/POST requests (or support both).

For example, if you want to support GET request, then tell the other sites they can perform operation on the Url above, with given parameters:
api_key, user_id, first_name (optional), last_name (optional)

**Example of the usage in their site:**

```
www.yoursite.com/api/updateprofile?api_key="key"&user_id=1&first_name="joe's new first name!"
```

In order to implement it on you site, simply parse the request and try to fetch the parameters, while validating the API key.

**I think the syntax in PHP is like the following though I am not sure:**

```
var api_key = GET["api_key"];
var user_id = GET["user_id"];
```

**Update 2:**

Here is a diagram to illustrate to you:

**Joe's user browser <----> Joe's server ---(API_KEY)---> Your site API**

The client has no access to the key, since Joe's server don't send it to the client at all,
the client don't even know your site exist.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks. So the Wordpress plugin running in Joe's website would have a PHP script that when Joe's visitor post the information they want to load to Joe's account in my website, instead of posting directly to my website they would post to the php script in Joe's server, which in turn will post to my website? Is that how I would go about implementing this? Thanks

Comment: thank you for updating your answer. However wouldn't the api key be visible to joe's visitor if they inspect the page in joe's site? Or you mean the call to my site would be done from a php script in joe's site, not from the browser?

Comment: The client can only see stuff that Joe's site sent to him. He has the html and the javascript, but he don't see his sever implementation and code. Therefore, he don't even know your site even exist and that Joe use it. I've added a diagram on the answer to illustrate it to you.